# Getting one value in single separated values and get count on each row in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have problem to get count of the same values on each row cause separated values.

[image: This is mytable in phpMyAdmin]

My question is: how to get only one value and get count on each row?

In this picture given,
I want the result like this:

The count of data '4' on each table row is 3.

If i select another value like 1:

The count of data '1' on each table row is 2.

I hope for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find in set like this

```
SELECT count(id) FROM `test` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5, mydata)
```

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php